# Using the word self in a class or its methods instead of just using the property name

Tags: ios, swift, self

When do we use the word self in a class or its methods instead of just using the property name?

For example in the code below one of the lines read, "self.ageLabel?.text = self.video?.timespan"

Why not just use "ageLabel?.text = video?.timespan"?  Or is this the same thing and it comes down to preference?

```
import UIKit

class VideoTableViewCell: ContactTableViewCell {

    var video: Video?

    @IBOutlet weak var picture: UIImageView?
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var ageLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var lawerLabel: UILabel?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        if UIScreen.mainScreen().isSmall() {
            self.updateFont(self.titleLabel)
            self.updateFont(self.ageLabel)
            self.updateFont(self.lawerLabel)
            self.updateButtonFont(self.phoneButton)
            self.updateButtonFont(self.emailButton)
        }
    }

    func updateFont(label: UILabel?) {
        label?.font = label?.font.fontByUpdatingSize()
    }

    func updateButtonFont(button: UIButton?) {
        button?.titleLabel?.font = button?.titleLabel?.font.fontByUpdatingSize()
    }

    func configureVideo(video: Video) {
        if let attorney = video.attorney {
            super.configure(attorney)
        }
        self.video = video
        if let thumb = video.thumb {

            self.picture?.loadImage(thumb, placeHolderName: "videoPlaceholder")


        }
        self.titleLabel?.text = self.video?.title
        self.ageLabel?.text = self.video?.timespan
    }
}
```

Comment: Both are functional, but you are required to use `self` when using closures because they are run asynchronous so they need a reference to the object that called them (which may be have been deleted in the external.synchronous scope).

Comment: @Putz1103 but in the above code "self.video = video" isn't inside a closure is it?  It looks like a normal function.

Comment: In that function I would say the `self` is required so that it doesn't get confused with matching `video` variables.  But I would just rename the input parameter in that function to avoid the clash.  That is bad code in my opinion.